# NSMutableArray from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

i have the following code and i want to use NSMutable arrays instead of NSArray
 could you tell me how to load the NSMutable array, as the current method does not work.

```
-(void) whatever{
NSData *htmlData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.objectgraph.com/contact.html"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *titles  = [xpathParser search:@"//h3"]; // get the page title - this is xpath     notation
TFHppleElement *title = [titles objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myTitles = [title content];

NSArray *articles  = [xpathParser search:@"//h4"]; // get the page article - this is xpath     notation
TFHppleElement *article = [articles objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myArtical = [article content];
```

i have tried :

```
NSMutableArray *titles  = [xpathParser search:@"//h3"];
```

but it does load the values?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can invoke `mutableCopy` on an `NSArray` object to return to you an `NSMutableArray`.

Note that the callee will obtain ownership of this object since the method name contains "copy".

([Apple's memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html) states that a method name containing the words "alloc", "new" or "copy" should by convention return an object which you own, and as such must relinquish ownership of at some point.)

Comment: I would up voted you but you wrote "should by convention return an object with a reference count = 1" which is technically wrong.  In fact if you read your own link you'll see it doesn't even use the phrase "retain count" in the object ownership policy section.

Comment: You've missed the point.  Apple's memory management guide says the convention is that you *own* the object.  It's an implementation detail that the retain count is 1 (which isn't always true anyway).

Answer (score 32):

Simply like this:

```
NSArray* someArray = [xpathParser search:@"//h3"];
NSMutableArray* mutableArray = [someArray mutableCopy];
```

That's quite literally, it.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `[xpathparser ...]` returns an `NSArray`, you can use:

```
NSMutableArray *titles  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[xpathParser search:@"//h3"]];
```

Comment: `+[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:]` has the benefit of being autoreleased - if you use `-[NSArray mutableCopy]`, you'll need to release/autorelease yourself.

Comment: Is comment by Nick Forge now irrelevant under ARC?

Comment: @BasilBourque no, some older but still maintained apps still use MRR

Comment: I'd still recommend my way if you're using MRC, just make sure to do `[[someArray mutableCopy] autorelease]` instead if you want it autoreleased.